# Compare group difference with replicates?

Tags: anova

I have a measurement for two groups of subjects where each subject contains 3 replicates. For example, the data is like below:

> Group Subject Replicate Value
>   1      A         1       0.2
>   1      A         2       0.3
>   1      A         3       0.25
>   1      B         1       0.4
>   1      B         2       0.3
>   1      B         3       0.7
>   2      C         1       0.2
>   2      C         2       0.1
>   2      C         3       0.3
>   2      D         1       0.4
>   2      D         2       0.2
>   2      D         3       0.25

I am thinking of using ANOVA where the subject is the error term,e.g. aov(Value~Group+Error(Subject)) in R. Is it correct?

Thanks!
Gim

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks essentially correct. You still have to specify the `data.frame` the values are taken from in `aov` like

```
aov(Value~Group+Error(Subject), data)
```

This model assumes that subject were taken at random (within their group). It is justified to drop the variable "replicate" from the formula as it bears no information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I recently came across a post using somehow a different formula for this case, e.g. a nested one way anova model as aov(Value~Group/Subject,data). The results are different. Which one is more correct?

Comment: Nope, I think the latter one is not what you want. The slash notation is short for aov(Value~Group+Group:Subject,data), which is a fixed effect model. Be careful of the confusion with the lme function from the nlme package, which uses the vertical bar | to specify error.

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to add the within group variance of subjects to (what has been already suggested),

`aov(Value~Group+Error(Subject), data)`

you could introduce the Group in the error term (adapted from [this answer](https://www.r-bloggers.com/two-way-anova-with-repeated-measures/)):

`aov(Value~Group+Error(Subject/Group), data)`

which is essentially:

`aov(Value~Group+Error(Subject+Subject:Group), data)`